# Basic Dagger example NoClassDefFoundError: dagger/internal/Preconditions

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have a very bare bones basic project that is giving me a NoClassDefFoundError.

Here is my gradle:

```
    plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.10"
}

group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    apt group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger-compiler', version: '2.14.1'
    compile group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: '2.14.1'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'test',
                'Implementation-Version': '1.0.0',
                'Main-Class': 'test.Main'
    }
    archiveName 'Test.jar'
}
```

And my Main class:

```
package test;

import dagger.Component;

public class Main {

    @Component(modules = { ServiceModule.class })
    interface Runner {
        ApplicationRunner runner();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner runner = DaggerMain_Runner.builder()
                .serviceModule(new ServiceModule())
                .build();
        runner.runner().execute();
    }
}
```

And My ServiceModule:

```
package test;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@Module
public class ServiceModule {
    @Provides
    public HelloService provideHelloService() {
        return new HelloServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

And HelloService:

```
package test;

public interface HelloService {
    void sayHello();
}
```

And HelloServiceImpl:

```
package test;

public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {
    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        System.err.println("HELLO");
    }
}
```

And finally ApplicationRunner:

```
package test;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class ApplicationRunner {
    public final HelloService helloService;

    @Inject
    public ApplicationRunner(HelloService helloService) {
        this.helloService = helloService;
    }

    public void execute() {
        helloService.sayHello();
    }
}
```

if I now run:

```
./gradlew clean build && java -jar build/libs/Test.jar
```

I get the following output:

> :clean :compileJava :processResources NO-SOURCE :classes :jar
>   :assemble :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
>   :testClasses UP-TO-DATE :test NO-SOURCE :check UP-TO-DATE :build
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 1.352 secs Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dagger/internal/Preconditions     at
>   test.DaggerMain_Runner$Builder.serviceModule(DaggerMain_Runner.java:49)
>     at test.Main.main(Main.java:14) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dagger.internal.Preconditions   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 2 more

Can anyone identify why I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError? For reference, line 14 of Main is the line that says:

```
.serviceModule(new ServiceModule())
```

I have tried changing things around quite a lot, using statics, injecting as a property etc. It seems though that I'm not understanding something fundamental here. The only way I could get this to work seemingly was to declare ServiceModule as abstract and use the @Bind annotation style. That's all very well, but what about when I actually want to use @Provides? I don't see why I can't use it in this way.

Comment: I have uploaded the source for this problem to my github here: https://github.com/SamAmco/DaggerFail  ... I will take it down once the problem is resolved.

Comment: *Can anyone identify why I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError?* - The created "Test.jar" isn't linked(or contains) the dependencies that you defined in the build.gradle file(the dagger dependency depends(and uses) on Google's Guava library). So you need to make the dependencies available to the jar which you can do by modifying your build.gradle file like in this gist I made: https://gist.github.com/luksprog/59e7e9c366c549caf3e0b940c87c777e .When you make the module abstract Dagger creates it on its own so it doesn't need to use the Guava Preconditions class(which isn't available).

Comment: Hi Luksporg. Thanks for the advice. Your suggestion seems to work. However I can't say I fully understand. I am relatively new to both gradle and dagger. With regard to dagger, I don't understand why this isn't mentioned in the documentation here: https://github.com/google/dagger